# Hash Tables in C

Tags: c, data-structures, hashtable

I am currently working on a 2d array version of a hash table implementation, where the rows will be equal to the hash space and the columns will hold the key-value pairs. However I am finding difficulty in understanding what is meant by hash space. Is it the actual size of the hash table or does it represent the space taken by the hash computed from the key ? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You may find [Coding up a Hash Table](http://www.sparknotes.com/cs/searching/hashtables/section3.rhtml) and [Hash tables - eternally confuzzled](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_hashtable.aspx) useful.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out... I referred to it already as I did a lot of research about hash tables as I'm just a beginner in C, however I was still unable to comprehend what is meant by hash space

Comment: I've never heard of implementing a hash with a 2D array. Usually it's an array (the "buckets") containing [linked lists of key/value pairs to handle collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution). "Hash space" is probably the size of your array, the "buckets".

Comment: @User18 *"Hash Space"* isn't a general term associated with hash tables. "*Load Factor*" is (which I presume is what you are getting at). It is the ratio of *filled buckets* to *total buckets* and in practice should not exceed `0.6` (in some cases `0.7` is acceptable).